# BroadcastReceiver not working in the background OREO+

Tags: java, android

In my application there are two receivers, one receives calls (`MyReceiverCall`) and the second SMS (`MyReceiverSms`).
When you start the app everything works fine, I get a notification when I receive an SMS or call.
But if I close the app in task Manager then nothing wants to work and all incoming SMS and calls are ignored by the receiver.
I had assumptions that can be simply service with my notification does not start, but through logs I understood that the receiver simply does not work. (But so far the assumption is that services are to blame)

**My code**

`MyReceiverCall.class`

```
public class MyReceiverCall extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String ACTION = "android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("123","sakuraso13 ReceiverCall");
        if (intent != null && intent.getAction() != null) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION)) {
                String number=intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING) & number!=null) {

                     // some operation with number phone
                        Intent intentService = new Intent(context, ServiceMain.class);
                        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
                            context.startForegroundService(intentService);

                        }else {
                            context.startService(intentService);
                        }
                }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

`MyReceiverSms.class`

```
   public class MyReceiverSms extends BroadcastReceiver {
        private static final String TAG="MyReceiverSms";
        private static final String ACTION="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.i("123","sakuraso13 ReceiverWorking");
            if(intent !=  null && intent.getAction()!=null) {
                if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION)) {
                    // some operation with number phone
                        Intent intentService=new Intent(context, ServiceMain.class);
                        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
                            context.startForegroundService(intentService);
                        }else {
                            context.startService(intentService);
                        }

                    }


                }
            }
        }

    }
```

`ServiceMain.class`

```
public class ServiceMain extends Service {


    public ServiceMain() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        return null;
    }



    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            startForegroundNotification();
        }
        showSimpleNotification(); 
    }
```

`AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="app.service.detector">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>

    <application
        android:name="detector.sakuraso13.App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <service
            android:name="detector.sakuraso13.Service.ServiceMain"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"></service>

        <receiver
            android:name="detector.sakuraso13.Broadcaster.MyReceiverCall"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"
                    android:priority="2147483647"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="detector.sakuraso13.Broadcaster.MyReceiverSms"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
            <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity android:name="detector.sakuraso13.Main.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Sometimes in logs I can see similar when calling when the application is closed:

```
2019-11-19 21:57:10.978 1271-1289/? W/BroadcastQueue: Permission Denial: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE flg=0x1000010 (has extras) } to app.service.detector/detector.sakuraso13.Broadcaster.MyReceiverCall requires android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE due to sender android (uid 1000)
2019-11-19 21:57:13.030 1271-6637/? W/BroadcastQueue: Permission Denial: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE flg=0x1000010 (has extras) } to app.service.detector/detector.sakuraso13.Broadcaster.MyReceiverCall requires android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE due to sender android (uid 1000)
```

Comment: I think that's expected behavior (when you kill app). I can imagine it helpful for safety reasons.

Comment: @ror but how can you make the receiver work even when the application is killed, otherwise how do applications that work with incoming SMS and calls